# Most popular items for a Site Collection in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports

I want to know the most popular items / most clicked items in my site. In SharePoint Server 2013, I can probably do this by using Audit Log reports, and then doing a report for the Most Viewed items.

However, in SharePoint Online I don't think it's available.

Is there a way that I can achieve what I want?

Thank you

Comment: I found this interesting article. Have you tried this. It has various steps with screen shots. It may help you http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/popularity-trends-in-your-sharepoint-online-team-site